# Is it possible to define a type for a nested object with variable depth?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that nests objects based on the length of an input array. E.g.:

```
fn(['a']) -> Record<string, string>

fn(['a', 'b']) -> Record<Record<string, string>>
```

I'm defining the return type as:

```
type Ret = {
  [k: string]: string | Ret;
}
```

However, this doesn't know the depth of the object. If the input as a TS tuple, then in theory it should be possible to know the depth of the return type. Is this currently possible?

Comment: AFAIK TypeScript support for [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) is limited. Your `Ret` type would need a "depth" parameter that is reduced. So you'd have `Ret<0> = string` and `Ret<n> = {[k: string]: Ret<n-1>}`, obviously this syntax is made up. Maybe [this article](https://www.hacklewayne.com/dependent-types-in-typescript), or [this one](https://www.hacklewayne.com/dependent-types-typescript-seriously) may help giving you some ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a recursively defined conditional type:

```
type NestedRecord<T extends any[]>
    = T extends [any, ...infer R]
    ? Record<string, NestedRecord<R>>
    : string
```

Example:

```
type Test = NestedRecord<['a', 'b']>
// {[x: string]: Record<string, string>}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMBKEDGB7ATsgPACpQQAeSAdsvFAIYUgDaAugHwBQUXUAvFMWUrUojeiAA0UAHQyAlhQBmEHFFTNO3APyrMuAohzyA5pLiIU6bHnypWHblABcUA8fbtQkfgmC9YPi11rRgByWhDJEIAjELZ2IA)